# Open another file in vim based off of the current file's name

Tags: vim

When working with Go I would like the ability to open the corresponding test file for each .go file I am working with, and vice versa. The format that is followed is `foo.go` corresponds to `foo_test.go`. I can assume that if it exists it will always be in the same folder. I do not care if it opens in a buffer, tab or even in the current buffer, I just want to press a button and be able to switch between the two. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some plugins that can switch between C/C++ `.c` and `.h` files; some may be so configurable to deal with your use case. However, such a mapping (or command) can be easily defined, e.g. for `<Leader>a`:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <Leader>a ':edit ' . (expand('%:t:r') =~? '_test$' ? expand('%:s?_test??') : expand('%:r') . '_test.' . expand('%:e')) . '<CR>'
```

This uses `:help filename-modifiers` to extract, compare, and assemble an `:edit` command.

The above is globally for use in `~/.vimrc`; if you want this only for Go files, use `:nnoremap <buffer> <expr> ...`
Then either prepend `:autocmd Filetype go`, and put that into your `~/.vimrc`, or, as that gets unwieldy as you add mappings and other settings for various filetypes, put the commands into `~/.vim/ftplugin/go_mappings.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

Answer (score 0):

For a drop-in solution to the problem, consider using my fork of the Go runtime files: https://github.com/AndrewRadev/vim-golang.

It defines the `:A` family of commands (relevant definitions are [here](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/vim-golang/blob/be6bfe2c7880ea1390bc31db72a9d55e9e89166d/ftplugin/go.vim#L7-12), filename modification is [here](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/vim-golang/blob/be6bfe2c7880ea1390bc31db72a9d55e9e89166d/autoload/go.vim#L55-63)).

It's basically Ingo Karkat's answer, packaged in a plugin, though, so reading up on `:help filename-modifiers` and following his advice is definitely a good way to go.

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend the plugin [vim-twitch](https://github.com/bodymindarts/vim-twitch) to address this issue.